# Update my counter into my database

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a database that stores a number of clicks. I can get the number of clicks that is in database and I can increment the clicks. The problem is that I can´t make put(update) of number clicks into my database. Here is my code:

```
function addClick(selecao) {
    console.log('addClick na seleção: ' + selecao.id_selecao);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: rootURLSelecoes + '/update/' + selecao.id_selecao,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

            var x = parseInt(selecao.clicks,10);
            x = x +1;

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('updateWine error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

The variable `x` stores the result that I want to store into my database, but I can´t figure out how to do this.